# Tensorflow: Why does Modulo (i.e. tf.math.floormod) not support unsigned integers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, modulo, unsigned-integer

From the [Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/floormod):

> *x*:   A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64,
>   bfloat16, half, float32, float64.

Example:

```
x = tf.math.mod(tf.constant(4, tf.dtypes.uint64), tf.constant(2, tf.dtypes.uint64))

[...]

NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node FloorMod}}
All kernels registered for op FloorMod :
  device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
 [Op:FloorMod]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed it out in the documentation as of now they only support these allowed datatypes.

```
int32, int64, bfloat16, half, float32, float64.
```

Still, if you want to pass the uint64 values, you need to convert it using numPy from uint64 to int64 and pass the int64 value to the `tf.math.mod` like below.

```
import numpy
input = numpy.int64( numpy.uint64(your_number))
```

You can raise an issue in Github for the same.